# Can't find my wordpress DB in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, wp-config, phpmyadmin

I have created a a site on my localhost, But Now I need to upload website on live server so i  need to export word press DB from Phpmyadmin, But I cant find any WP DB there.

Here is my **wp-config file**

```
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'bitnami_wordpress');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'bn_wordpress');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', '0cca6aaab5');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost:3306');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

**phpmyadmin config file**

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '123456';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';


/* Advanced phpMyAdmin features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma__bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma__relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma__table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma__table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma__pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma__column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma__history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma__designer_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma__recent';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] = 'pma__users';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] = 'pma__usergroups';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] = 'pma__navigationhiding';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] = 'pma__savedsearches';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['central_columns'] = 'pma__central_columns';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_settings'] = 'pma__designer_settings';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['export_templates'] = 'pma__export_templates';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] = 'pma__favorite';
```

**Here is my phpmyadmin screenshot**

[image]

I have logged in my phpmyadmin through root user, so i have all the privileges (in case)

Can anyone tell me what's the issue here ??

Comment: based on the DB name it seems like bitnami was used to set wordpress and bitnami has all kind of annoying properties, although hiding DBs in phpmyadmin should not be one of them. If I am right, the right place to ask is bitnami support

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason to login as root if you only need the one database... Have you tried logging in to phpMyAdmin as the user with the same credentials as your WordPress installation?

```
user: bn_wordpress
pass: 0cca6aaab5
port: 3306
```

We could avoid phpMyAdmin all together... From the command line you can dump the database using the following:

```
mysqldump -u [uname] -p[pass] db_name > db_backup.sql
```

A simpler *(more user-friendly/non-technical) being to dump the db via wp-admin using a backup/export plugin.

I'm partial to WP-Migrate DB for small dumps like this, but duplicator, all export pro, any of the WordPress backup/migration plugins can do the job of dumping your MySQL data for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin named 'adminer'. You can use that.

And my all time favourite for moving wordpress site is "Duplicator"

You can get that from :  https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

Answer (score 0):

I have a well-tweaked procedure I use to move a site from development to a live site (or from one hosting place to another).

It involves creating a base WP install on the new place, then copying files and data from the old place to the new place. And then using the Better Search and Replace plugin to fix any incorrect URLs in the database.

It's a bit involved (and too long) to post as an answer, but I've used the process many times so it has worked well for me. Look [here](https://securitydawg.com/moving-a-wordpress-site/).

As for creating a new WP site, most hosting places have a 'wizard' that will create a base WP installation. But then you have to move files and data from development to the new place.

And I have tried many different 'automated' processes to do it, but they weren't always successful, and sometimes required purchase of the premium version to complete the task. So I developed my own process.

You'll also find many other resources/tutorials on the same subject. I used those as a basis for my process, and then added tweaks as I have done more of them.